# Как преобразовать битовые операторы из Java в Delphi?

Tags: java, delphi, android-studio

Требуется скопировать небольшую функцию с Java (Android Studio) на Delphi, для этого необходимо функцию эту переделать немного так как синтаксис отличается. Столкнулся с проблемой при редактировании, не понимаю что значат данные строки:

**Код в Java:**

```
public static long get(byte[] bytes, int offset, int bytesCount) {
   if (bytes.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty array");
   } else {
      long result = 0;
      for (int i = offset; i < offset + bytesCount; i++) {
         result ^= (((long) bytes[i]) & 255) << ((((bytesCount - 1) + offset) - i) * 8);
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

**Не понятна следующая строка:**

```
result ^= (((long) bytes[i]) & 255) << ((((bytesCount - 1) + offset) - i) * 8);
```

**Мои наработки на данный момент в Delphi (до данной строки):**

```
function get(bytes: array of byte; offset,bytesCount: integer):LongInt;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  if (length(bytes) = 0) then begin
  end else begin
    result := 0;
    for i := offset to (offset + bytesCount) do begin
```

Прошу объяснить и написать как будут выглядеть строки в Delphi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это битовые операторы (Bitwise Operators):

`<<` - оператор смещения влево (`shl` - http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=shl)
`^` - оператор `xor`
`&` - оператор битового `and`

А здесь дополнительное описание всех операторов и деталей их работы: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/expressions_xml.html

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я все таки не понимаю как можно xor-присваивание сделать, пожалуйста, приведите пример как мне лучше всего написать?

Comment: @vip72, вероятно, можно заменить xor-присваивание (`result ^= something`) на xor с последующим присваиванием (`result = result ^ something`)

Comment: @diraria спасибо, упустил из виду отсутствие в Delphi короткой записи

Comment: А как повторить следующий кусок? 
(((long) bytes[i]) & 255)
Я написал так:
(PLongInt(bytes[i]) AND 255)
Но возникает ошибка:
Operator not applicable to this operand type
Я так понимаю ошибка из-за несоответствия типов...

Comment: @vip72 уберите `P` из `PLongInt`